# General Questions about installation of igraph and other programs

Tags: r

I am struggling to complete simple task again on R now that I'm using a different computer. Windows instead of Mac.... anyways. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction as to how to install igraph? I'm attempting to install igraph and I get this messsage...

installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status

I then proceeded to look up why this was occuring, realized that I need Rtools(which I have already) and additionally glpx,lbxm2,and gmp. Which I am also struggling to dowload.. can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: RStudio does not provide a package manager.

Comment: What was the full output you got when you ran `install.packages("igraph")`? Usually there is a more specific error message above the "non-zero exit" message. What version of R are you using? You should not need RTools if you are just downloading a compiled package from CRAN as long as your version is up to date. If it asks you if you want to build form source, be sure to choose "No". The precompiled binary should be fine.

Comment: compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf:238: feedback_arc_set.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'igraph'
* removing 'C:/Users/WiensDell3/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/igraph'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: In file included from feedback_arc_set.c:31:
igraph_glpk_support.h:36:10: fatal error: glpk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glpk.h>

Comment: i need glpk to install it but I don't know how to install glpk because its not in the CRAN directory

Comment: Using most recent version of R just downloaded it today.

Comment: Restart R. Did it ask you if you want to install from source? Make sure to choose "no" and just use the precompiled binary for Windows. Or you can wait a few days till the binary for the newest version (which was updated yesterday) has made it to all the CRAN mirrors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `Rtools` on Windows.
Then you need to add a line in your `.Renviron` that refers to said Rtools installation. Please read [this](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) carefully. Especially the part that says this line has to be in your `.Renviron`-file: `PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\usr\bin;${PATH}"`.

I'd use `usethis::edit_r_environ()` to locate the important file.

Secondly, if you need to install anything, then use `{installr}`-package.

### Second part

In case you need to install something as part of the Rtools installation, you need to do the following:

1. Press Windows-Key and write `Rtools Bash`. Wait until it finds it, and press Enter.
2. This will give you a bash terminal within the rtools environment.
3. Write `pacman -Sy` in there and press Enter.
4. Then write `pacman -Sy mingw-w64-{i686,x86_64}-glpk mingw-w64-{i686,x86_64}-libxml2 mingw-w64-{i686,x86_64}-gmp` and press Enter. (Or whatever else you need to install

This should then do what is needed to install those missing components.

Comment: Thank you, my Rtools is functional.  I'm just getting non-zero exit status on igraph and am not finding glpx, ibxml2 nor gmp to install

Comment: How can I get this to work for installation? pacman -Sy mingw-w64-{i686,x86_64}-glpk mingw-w64-{i686,x86_64}-libxml2 mingw-w64-{i686,x86_64}-gmp

Comment: I need to be walked through the process

Comment: I wrote a quick answer.

Comment: right on! awesome, it worked. sweetness you all know on here. appreciate the expertise for us non-computer capable folks.

Comment: you're welcome! If you can mark my answer as the answer, so that I can get those sweet, sweet internet-points, then maybe my late night hacking could be deemed worth it after all. :D

Comment: one last question, they seemed to donwload but how do I now access them on Rstudio to be used in the installation of igraph?

Comment: You don't. If you configured the path correctly, then building the packages (from source) would just work, and those packages will access the underlying things. If you have another error when building the packages, then do tell.